# React Native register form with back-end mongodb and node xpress

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mern

I have this code below related to register in react native:

```
handleSubmit = () =>{
    event.preventDefault(event);
    //  console.log(this.state)
    let _this = this
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register', this.state.data)
    .then( res => {
        console.log('res', res);
        if(res.data.errors){
            let mainErrors = res.data.errors;
            let err_msg = {
                email: mainErrors.email ? mainErrors.email.msg : '',
                password: mainErrors.password ? mainErrors.password.msg : '',
            };
            _this.setState({
                error: err_msg,
                success: ''
            })
        }else{
            _this.setState({
                data:{
                    email:'',
                    password:'',
                },
                error:{
                    email:'',
                    password:'',
                },
                success:'Thank you for registering'
            })
        }
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error)})
}
```

My problem is that it gives me an error while running because of this line: `event.preventDefault(event);`

Comment: Kindly visit first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here your `event` is not definded

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in event as an argument:

```
handleSubmit=(event)=>{
  ...
}
```